# How to copy files from folders and subfolders and paste to a single folder?

Tags: server, files, directory

I want to copy all the final files from parent folder and  child folders to a different folder. How to do that?

Comment: I believe you need to rewrite the question a bit, no idea what you mean.

Comment: `cp -p /path/final_files\* /path/subpath/`  -- but you'll need to adjust as your question is unclear.  I use the -p to preserve file attributes (mode, ownership, timestamps) assuming you want to keep this.

Comment: You want to make a directory with a flat structure containing the files from a multi-level structure, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood is that you want to copy all files from a folder which has sub-folders to a destination folder.

You can use:

```
find source_directory -type f -exec cp -t destination_folder "{}" \+
```

Or you can just use the copy command as suggested in the comments like:

```
cp -p source_directory/* destination_directory
```